# Loop con condición entre una celda y un rango

Tags: excel, vba

En primer lugar, el objetivo es diseñar un secuenciador de salidas, de forma que, al introducir un valor que es el tiempo en el que quieres salir y pulsar un botón al que se le asociaría la macro, esta macro me daría el primer tiempo disponible para tu salida, ya que previamente alguien ha podido solicitar la misma hora que tú.

Tras explicar el objetivo muestro el código y explico su aplicación dentro de la hoja excel. En la columna Z (TOBT manual) empezando en Z4, los usuarios introducirán un tiempo objetivo en el que quieren salir, al pulsar el botón situado a la derecha de este tiempo introducido (macro asociada al botón), se debería comprobar que este tiempo no está ya introducido en la columna AB (TSAT) empezando en AB4. Por lo que, si el valor no se encuentra en ese rango de la columna AB, se sitúa el valor de la columna Z en la columna AB. Si este si se encuentra se le suma 2 minutos y se vuelve a comprobar si este tiempo existe en la columna AB, así hasta encontrar un tiempo libre.

Cabe recalcar, que el formato que se está empleando ahora mismo es el personalizado "hh:mm", y que no debe haber distinción de días, ya que se estará ejecutando todo en un intervalo de tiempo de un mismo día. Adjunto imagen del excel para mejor visualización, y el código empleado que asigna el error "13 No coinciden los tipos":
[image: Ventana Excel]

```
Dim VALTSAT1 As Date
VALSAT1 = Z4

Do While VALSAT1 = Range("AB4:AB19")
    VALSAT1 = DateAdd(n, 2, VALSAT1)

    Exit Do

    AB4 = VALSAT1
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Pues con este código lo tendrías, ten en cuenta que tomará como referencia la hora de la celda que haya seleccionada en el momento de la ejecución.

Por lo mismo, puedes tener únicamente un botón que se encargaría de hacer el cálculo para cualquier celda:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GrabarTOBT()

    Dim HorasOcupadas As Object: Set HorasOcupadas = CargaHorasOcupadas
    Dim HoraStr As String
    Dim HoraDeseada As Date
    HoraDeseada = ActiveCell.Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Dim HoraOcupada As Boolean: HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        Dim lrow: lrow = ActiveCell.Row
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With

End Sub
Private Function CargaHorasOcupadas() As Object
    Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        Dim lrow As Long: lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 3 Then
            Dim C As Range
            Dim Hora As String
            For Each C In .Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)
                Hora = Format(C, "hh:mm")
                Dict.Add Hora, 1
            Next C
        End If
    End With
    Set CargaHorasOcupadas = Dict

End Function
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo integre con otras piezas de código y funciona a la perfección excepto por un detalle. Va situando los tiempos uno tras otro en la linea AB, cuando la idea es, que al introducir un tiempo no tiene porque ser el siguiente y por ello al guardarse secuencialmente, la linea en la que se encontraba el valor TOBT Manual (columna Z) no está en la misma columna que el resultado que brinda el código.

Comment: Es decir, al empezar desde el Z4, lo hace perfecto, el Z5 también, pero si el siguiente valor que se introduce es el Z7 y se ejecuta el código, lo introduce en la AB6 en vez de la 7, ¿Como se podría solucionar este detalle? Por el resto cumple la función perfectamente

Comment: Mira mi código editado, con eso debería bastar @IgnacioOteroLacaci

Comment: Esta perfecto, hace todo lo necesario a la perfección.

Comment: Existe un problema Damian con al función que no acabo de solucionar desconozco el motivo. Al tratar de realizar este proceso en dos celdas no simultáneas (una posterior y otra anterior) me salta el error "Error '457': this key is already associated with an element of this collection", subrayando al frase                 Dict.Add Hora, 1. Desconozco el porque secuencialmente funciona perfectamente pero en desorden no. Sabrías el motivo?